# How to show that the composition of two surjective functions is injective?

Tags: functions

I know how to show the composition of two surjective functions is surjective or two injective functions is injective, but I don't understand this case problem.

Comment: Is your task to prove it, or is your task to determine whether it is true and then prove your answer?

Comment: Have you looked at examples?  I mean, suppose one of the functions is the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because it's not true. Here is a counter-example.

Simplifying Linda's answer, take sets $A=\{a,b\}$ and $B=\{q\}$
and constant function $f: A\to B$ and identity function $g:B\to B$.

Then
$$g\circ f$$
is a surjection but not an injection.

Answer (score 2):

That's not true in general.We can take a counterexample to show one case when it is not true:

Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ be two surjective functions and let $h:A\to C$ be their composition such that: $A=\{a,b\}$,$B=\{c,d\}$ and $C=\{e\}$ then

$f(a)=c$; $f(b)=d$ and

$g(c)=e$; $g(d)=e$

It is obvious that $h(a)=e$ and $h(b)=e$ so $h$ is not injective.

So we found an example where the composition of two surjective functions is not injective, therefore your statement is not always true.